# Lattice in Sage: Generate matrix A from a basis S such that AS = 0 (mod q)

Tags: lattice-crypto, trapdoor

In Sage, there is a function: gen_lattice() that can generate a basis $$S \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times m}_q $$ of a lattice $$\Lambda^\bot_q(A)$$, where $$A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times m}_q$$ is a random.

Therefore, $$AS = 0 \pmod q.$$

The question is: is there any method that can further obtain a matrix $$A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times m}_q.$$

(i.e., the TrapGen algorithm in [AP09](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/521.pdf).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is relatively straightforward.
First, it seems that Sage has this built-in (see the [dual flag](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/cryptography/sage/crypto/lattice.html), although I didn't test it).
I'll describe the "mathematical" way to proceed, as I think it is conceptually more useful.

For a lattice with basis $B$, it is well-known (see [theorem 2](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp14/cse206A-a/lec3.pdf)) that the dual has basis:

$$D = B (B^t B)^{-1}$$

It follows that the following code snippet:

```
S = sage.crypto.gen_lattice()
D = S * (S.T * S).inverse()
```

will generate the desired basis. Note that the basis is not an integer matrix in general --- for a (random) matrix $S$ generated in an execution of `sage.crypto.gen_lattice()`, I get that the dual basis is:

```
[ 1/11     0     0     0 -4/11 -3/11  2/11     0]
[    0  1/11     0     0 -5/11  1/11 -3/11     0]
[    0     0  1/11     0     0  5/11 -4/11 -5/11]
[    0     0     0  1/11 -2/11  4/11  4/11 -5/11]
[    0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0]
[    0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0]
[    0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0]
[    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1]
```

The (primal) basis was chosen to be $q$-ary for $q = 11$.
You might notice that by scaling things up by $q = 11$, we get an integer matrix.
This holds in general, and can be seen by noting that a $q$-ary lattice $L$ satisfies:

\begin{align*}
q\mathbb{Z}^m&\subseteq L\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^m\\
\iff (q\mathbb{Z}^m)^*&\supseteq L^* \supseteq \mathbb{Z}^m\\
\iff \frac{1}{q}\mathbb{Z}^m&\supseteq L^*\supseteq \mathbb{Z}^m\\
\iff \mathbb{Z}^m &\supseteq qL^*\supseteq q\mathbb{Z}^m
\end{align*}

This is to say that if $q\mathbb{Z}^m\subseteq L\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^m$, then while the dual lattice $L^*$ may not be contained between $q\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $\mathbb{Z}^m$, the *scaled* dual lattice always is.
One often sees this in papers as the statement:

$$\Lambda_q(A)^* = \frac{1}{q}\Lambda_q^\perp(A)$$

In fact, in the notation of $\Lambda_q(A)$ and $\Lambda_q^\perp(A)$, you are simply asking, given a basis for $\Lambda_q(A)$, to construct a basis for $\Lambda_q^\perp(A)$.

Comment: In addition, after running your code, it seems that A*S cannot obtain 0. Thanks

Comment: I forgot a transpose, in the notation of the answer it holds that $(qD)^t S = q D^t S\equiv 0 \bmod q$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it!